# Can you dynamically generate regions in Oracle APEX using PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

APEX newbie here. Is it possible to generate regions dynamically with pl/sql? We have a lot of permits that have a certain subsection which should have its own region. The thing is, these subsections could be zero or many, so we want a way to dynamically create regions based on each permit. Is this doable?

Using APEX 4.2

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to put in this regions? If reports - it can be quite hard, if items or static text - it will a bit easier. In any case, you can look at html code of region, then create `PL/SQL region` and put inside it generated html for other regions. Provide more details, and I can try to make an example.

Comment: Also, you should create static regions and use its `Security` section and APEX's authorization schemas, if the only reason for your question is security and permissions.

Comment: A region can only appear once (at most). If you want two regions, create two regions. It sounds like what you want is a report, where each record is rendered in what *looks like* a region. It won't be straightforward but you can do this by using a standard report and generating the HTML in your report SQL.

Comment: So can I make an interactive report using a dynamic PL/SQL region? Is there an example I can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what you will be doing in the regions but my prefered method is to create a single PL/SQL Dyanamic Content region which simply calls some stored procedure.

then I can edit the stored procedure, with access to all the global variables via the v() function

```
l_user varchar2(500) := v('APP_USER');
```

You can then generate html code with htp.prn(); (or htp.p() )

You can create pretty complex pages in Apex using dynamic content while keeping the actual Apex page relatively simple.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. But can I generate multiple dynamic content regions at a time? Because each of our permits can have multiple subsections (with many addresses, descriptions, etc) that I want to stick inside jQuery accordions. So ideally I want a script that creates a region for each subsection for each permit at runtime (since this is a permit search app). Can I do this with APEX?

Comment: Yes,  If you know your html/javascript you can pretty much do anything within a dynamic content block.   You can even create a report, have it unskinned, and create the html in the select (remember to disable the escaping of html)

Apex API: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/toc.htm

Apex JS api: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/javascript_api.htm#CDEEIGFH

Comment: Web toolkit reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15896/pshtp.htm

Though it's easier to simply always use HTP.P and OWA_UTIL.

Comment: OK I see how I can do it in theory. Thanks!